# Memory allocation to class members in c++

Tags: c++

I have one simple question here,

```
template <class T, MAX_ITEMS>
Class A{
public:
  T buf[MAX_ITEMS];
}

A<class_name, 1000> obj_A;
```

When I declare obj_A using the last line, does it reserve a space? for sizeof(class_name)*1000 or it would reserve only if I use the new keyword for declaring obj_A?

Comment: *"does it reserve a space? for sizeof(class_name)*1000"* Yes. Depending on type, that may cause stack overflow, but at least it tries.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili _"... that may cause stack overflow ..."_ No, at least not in the OP's example. Stack memory is only in play for function local variables.

Comment: I don't agree with the downvoting, the question is legit, I agree the same information could be found in various tutorial and a bit of googling, however, C++ can be daunting with new comers and if somebody is not familiar with templates can be easily be confused

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You are right. I presumed OP wants to do that in function scope as well.

Answer (score 1):

> does it reserve a space? for sizeof(class_name)*1000 or it would reserve only if I use the new keyword for declaring obj_A?

Yes, it will allocate enough memory for 1000 elements of that type statically. If your object has static/thread storage duration, then it is likely to work. If your object has automatic storage duration, depending on the type and stack size, it may cause stack overflow.

> or it would reserve only if I use the new keyword for declaring obj_A?

If you use the `new` keyword, it will allocate the memory dynamically (dynamic storage duration). It generally doesn't matter how you create the object; if you manage to create an object of `A<class_name, 1000>` type successfully, it will surely have room for 1000 objects of type `class_name` in it.

Learn more about storage durations [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).